# How do you change the reset password URL in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using [meteor](http://meteor.com) along with the [accounts-password](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api) package. I'm rolling my own login and password changing/resetting UI and want to know...

**How can I customize the password reset link in the reset password email sent as a result of `Accounts.resetPassword`?**

Currently it in the form like so: `/#/reset-password/<id>'`. Since I am using [meteor router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router), I would like to send in the form `'/reset-password/<id>'`so I can catch it with the route `'/reset-password/:id'`.

Comment: Much better explained answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539216/how-to-reset-password-in-meteor-application/49996724#49996724

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [section on email templates in the Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_emailtemplates):

> resetPassword: An Object with two fields:
>
> - resetPassword.subject: A Function that takes a user object and returns a String for the subject line of a reset password email.
> - resetPassword.text: A Function that takes a user object and a **url**, and returns the body text for a reset password email.

You can customise which url is passed to the reset password email method:

```
Accounts.resetPassword.text = function(user, url) {
  return "Click this link to reset your password: /reset-password/" + myId;
}
```

Comment: Aha, I just could not find that section. Thanks.

Comment: Wait how do I get ```myId```? The url passed into the function looks like the original one I wanted to change.

Comment: `myId` was just an example, you should implement the method yourself however you want.

Comment: Okay, I got it working with this snippet:
```
Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.text = function(user, url) {
  var id = url.split('/')[5];
  return "Click this link to reset your password: /reset-password/" + id;
}
```

Comment: ```var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)``` is probably a safer bet given that the base url might change.

Comment: Wait am I being foolish there. Is it a specially generated token just for that email in the URL, or the user's document object id there?

Comment: That's up to you, but it's probably best to use a generated token so people can't reset each other's passwords by guessing the url :)

Comment: Well thats what I figured meteor did by default, which is why I have to get the id they generated in that fashion, so I can use the rest of the built in accounts password stuff.

Comment: is this working really ? I am gettting error "Cannot set property 'siteName' of undefined" when I set the value of Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName and "Cannot read property 'resetPassword' of undefined " error when set the function for  Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.text. I need to change the forgot password email body. Pls help out.

Comment: I have to say I find Rahul's answer - where he slips in "myId" without any explanation - to be most unhelpful.  After all, substringing the url parameter is the absolute crux of modifying the link for the email. Its only thanks to @Diogenes that I could make sense of his answer.  I wish he'd update his original answer to include his example of getting the reset token from the url

Answer (score 57):

Late to the party ...

Instead of changing the whole text, you can just change the url with:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
 Accounts.urls.resetPassword = function(token) {
    return Meteor.absoluteUrl('reset-password/' + token);
  };
});
```

Comment: modifying the url works just great but the sent token is another one for some reason

Comment: I knew when I saw @david-lawson was involved in this answer it was going to be the gold I was looking for! Saved me a lot of hassle - wish I found it sooner. Why is this not in the docs??? Thanks guys.

Comment: Great solution, seems to me that Accounts.urls is not documented in Meteor-docs.

Comment: [Found a quick mention of it in the docs here](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#email-flows) Note: `Accounts.urls` needs to be called in server only code. This confused me for a minute because the context where it's mentioned in the docs is right after `Accounts.onResetPasswordLink` which is client only.

Answer (score 18):

It has changed a little bit:

You have to use

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.text
```

For the url you can simply replace the hashbang instead of parsing the token from the url. As an example (in coffeescript):

```
Meteor.startup(() ->
  Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.text = (user, url) ->
     url = url.replace('#/', '')
     return "Click this link to reset your password: " + url
)
```

ES6

```
Meteor.startup(() =>
  Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.text = function(user, url) {
     url = url.replace('#/', '');
     return `Click this link to reset your password: ${url}`;
   }
);
```