# Meteor reset password - clicking on e-mail link doesn't work

Tags: url, hash, meteor, token

Trying to implement password recovery in my meteor app.

I can generate an recovery email which points to my app :

`onemore.meteor.com/#/reset-Password/[token]`

When I click on this link, it goes to the URL, but then the URL immediately rewrites to `onemore.meteor.com/#`

When I type `Session.get("resetPassword")`, it returns `undefined`

I know the token is valid. If I copy the latter part of the link in the e-mail "[token]" and paste it into console, as `Session.set("resetPassword",[token])`, the password recovery form acts as expected.

Why does my URL rewrite onload? Should this happen? Is there js that I need to interpret this before the rewrite?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might try removing the # from reset URL with something like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {       

  Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.text = function (user, url) {
     url = url.replace('#/', '')
     return " To reset your password, simply click the link below:\n\n"
       + url;
  };
});
```

See also [How do you change the reset password URL in meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130310/how-do-you-change-the-reset-password-url-in-meteor)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the route by yourself.

For iron router with coffeescript it may like

```
Router.route '#/reset_password/:token',
  name: 'reset_password'
  onBeforeAction: ()->
    if Meteor.userId() then this.redirect('/') else this.next()
    Accounts._resetPasswordToken = this.params.token
```

And you should also add the reset_password template.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the URL as follows:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    Accounts.urls.resetPassword= (token)  => {
        return Meteor.absoluteUrl('reset-password/' + token);
    };
});
```

Thats better than replacing the whole email text.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for a long time, and it is finally resolved.

As it turns out, the process that does a reset password stores the resetPasswordToken in your session variables.

In my case, I was clearing all session variables whenever the userId changed, which would wipe out the token, which disabled the dialog from appearing.

I now clear only the session variables I use (instead of calling Session.clear() ) and the problem finally was resolved.